# AND? OR? IF? count the orders complying 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables:

- 1st t "ORDERS" - columns: customer nr, order nr, payment method
- 2nd t "STATUSES" - columns: order nr, the order status

I want to count for specific customers, the amount of:

- 'shipped' orders paid by credit card (CC)
- plus amount of 'canceled' orders paid another way.

I would like to have the result in one column.

```
select c_id, count(*) 
from orders o
join statuses s on o.o_nr = s.o_nr
where o.c_id in (1, 2)
?
group by o.c_id
```

In details:

ORDERS

```
c_id | o_nr | pm
1    | 0004 | CC
1    | 0009 | CC
2    | 0011 | CC
2    | 0018 | installment
2    | 0020 | gift ;)
```

STATUSES

```
o_nr | status
0004 | shipped
0009 | in_progress
0011 | shipped
0018 | canceled
0020 | canceled
```

The result should be:

```
c_id | count (*)
1    | 1
2    | 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
SELECT o.c_id
     , COUNT(*) 
  FROM orders o
  JOIN statuses s
    ON s.o_nr = o.o_nr
   AND ( (s.status = 'shipped' AND o.pm = 'CC')
      OR (s.status = 'canceled' AND o.pm <> 'CC')
       )
 WHERE o.c_id in (1, 2)
 GROUP BY o.c_id
```

---

For this type of query, I sometimes find it advantageous to move the conditional tests into expressions in the SELECT list; this is useful when I want to return 0 counts, and I want to include the same rows in more than one "count"...

For example:

```
SELECT o.c_id
     , SUM(s.status = 'shipped' AND o.pm = 'CC')     AS shipped_and_cc
     , SUM(s.status = 'canceled' AND o.pm <> 'CC')   AS canceled_not_cc
     , SUM((s.status = 'shipped' AND o.pm = 'CC')
        OR (s.status = 'canceled' AND o.pm <> 'CC')) AS sac_and_cnc
     , SUM(1)                                        AS total_orders  
  FROM orders o
  JOIN statuses s
    ON s.o_nr = o.o_nr
 WHERE o.c_id in (1, 2)
 GROUP BY o.c_id
```